# weak-weak convergence of continuous operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let F: H \to H is a Lipschitz continuous operator, where H is a Hilbert space.
Let x_k converges weakly to x. How do I prove that F(x_k) converges weakly to F(x)?
Some books or references?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is linear you can use the adjoint $F^*$ of $F$:
$$<F(x_k),y>=<x_k,F^*(y)>\rightarrow <x,F^*(y)>=<F(x),y>.$$
If $F$ is nonlinear, I am not sure, if the statement is still correct. The counterexample I have in mind looks as follows, but I did not check every detail, since I am a bit short on time right now:

Put 
$$H=l^2:=\{(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{R}|\ \sum_{k=1}^\infty(a_k)^2<\infty\}.$$
and the sequence $(x_k)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}=(\delta_{ki})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}.$
$x_k$ converges weakly to zero. Now put 
$$F(x)=(\|x\|_{l^2},0,0,\ldots).$$
Here 
$$\|a\|_{l^2}^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(a_k)^2$$
is the norm of $l^2$. 
Hence
$$F(x_k)=(1,0,\ldots),$$
which does not converge weakly to zero.